# connecting to the actvie directory of a org

Tags: java, jsp, active-directory, ldap

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String domain="xyz.domain.com";
      String ldapHost="ldap://xyz.domain.com:389";
      String searchBase = "cn=users,dc=dom,dc=com";
      Scanner sn=new Scanner(System.in);
        String user=sn.next();
        String password=sn.next();
      String returnedAtts[] ={ "sn", "givenName", "mail" };
      String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + user + "))";

      //Create the search controls
      SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
      searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);

      //Specify the search scope
      searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

      Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
      env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
      env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapHost);

      env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

      env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user + "@" + domain);

      env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

      LdapContext ctxGC = null;
      boolean ldapUser = false;

      try
      {
            ctxGC = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

            //Search objects in GC using filters
            NamingEnumeration answer = ctxGC.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);

            while (answer.hasMoreElements())
            { 
                  SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();
                  Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                  Map amap = null;
                  if (attrs != null)
                  { 
                        amap = new HashMap();
                        NamingEnumeration ne = attrs.getAll();
                        while (ne.hasMore())
                        {       
                              Attribute attr = (Attribute) ne.next();
                              amap.put(attr.getID(), attr.get());
                              ldapUser = true;

                        }
                        ne.close();
                  }

            }
            if(ldapUser=true)
            {

            }
            else{

            }

      }
      catch (NamingException ex)
      {
            ex.printStackTrace();

      }
```

i just need to authenticate the user and password. but cant figure out what the problem is. should i add security protocol(ssl/tls)? javx.Nmaing.AuthenticationException pops every time when i run it on the server? i cant hardly do anything. hlep me out. 
thank you!

Comment: It would help if you a) formatted your code some more and b) gave us the exact Exception. It's okay to leave out usernames but the Exception gives details that might help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably this line:

`env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user + "@" + domain);`

You are constructing a username that may not be valid. For this to work, the user's `userPrincipalName` needs to match `user + "@" + domain`. Try using just `user`.